How magento handle new request on "*/*/ "?
This my request

NewAction.php to handle the request


this is result of request
I don't have blog_post_new layout, How it will work ?

This issue occurred because your NewAction controller extends the Post controller, which means it inherits the layout from the Post controller. As a result, the Post controller's layout is being used in your NewAction controller.

yes sir I  got it, thank you very much

This is not Magento codebase, but a third-party module, specially Magefan_Blog.

The \Magefan\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\NewAction class
extends the \Magefan\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Post class. Reference: https://github.com/magefan/module-blog/blob/2.11.4/Controller/Adminhtml/Post/NewAction.php
The \Magefan\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Post class
extends the \Magefan\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Actions class. Reference:  https://github.com/magefan/module-blog/blob/2.11.4/Controller/Adminhtml/Post.php
The \Magefan\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Actions class
extends the \Magefan\Community\Controller\Adminhtml\Actions class. Reference:  https://github.com/magefan/module-blog/blob/2.11.4/Controller/Adminhtml/Actions.php

The \Magefan\Community\Controller\Adminhtml\Actions class, is designed to  handle requests for a list of actions, including 'index', 'grid', 'new', 'edit', 'save', 'duplicate', 'delete', 'config', and 'massStatus'. Reference: https://github.com/magefan/module-community/blob/2.1.28/Controller/Adminhtml/Actions.php
/**
 * Action execute
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
 */
public function execute()
{
    $_preparedActions = ['index', 'grid', 'new', 'edit', 'save', 'duplicate', 'delete', 'config', 'massStatus'];
    $_action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
    if (in_array($_action, $_preparedActions)) {
        $method = '_'.$_action.'Action';

        $this->_beforeAction();
        $this->$method();
        $this->_afterAction();
    }
}

The new action, in turn, being handled by the call $this->_newAction():
/**
 * New action
 * @return void
 */
protected function _newAction()
{
    $this->_forward('edit');
}

As a result, the new action (<base_url>/admin/blog/post/new), is forwarded to the edit action (<base_url>/admin/blog/post/edit). The edit action has its layout file declared at <Magefan_Blog_module_dir>/view/adminhtml/layout/blog_post_edit.xml. Reference: https://github.com/magefan/module-blog/blob/2.11.4/view/adminhtml/layout/blog_post_edit.xml

Thank you for your explaination, i completely understood <3
